# Adding and accepting score

Tags: usability, forms, validation

I'm working on a app where tennis players can add score. When a player starts playing he is starting the streaming service and invites the other player. After the game a "post session page" will turn up where the players can add a personal note, winner and the score. The personal note will only be visible to yourself, but the score will be shown to the other player, so that he can confirm it.

Im a bit confused over this race condition where one player can add a score in the post session page and the other can do it aswell. I want to give them both the opportunity to add score, but it gets a bit complex if they both add different score. The easiest way would be to just say that one player can add score and then the other one will recieve a message in the app where he can confirm it. So I have two questions:

1. Is it okay to have the save button represent the saving for the whole form (personal note, winner and score). Or should the personal have a seperate save button of its own?
2. How should I handle the score? I want them to be able to add score and "agreeing" on a score in the end. Is there any other good examples out there which I can gain knowledge from?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**To your first question**: On a mobile screen, it's always a good idea to show/ask one thing at a time. Also, based how you want to handle score confirmation, it might be better suited to a pop-up card of its own.

**To your second question**: Let's first look at the problem. Your use case calls for 3 distinct scenarios:

- Play hasn't started yet, one player streams and invites another.
- Play has started. Both players have access to scoring/ notes.
- Play has ended. Player 1 has entered a score of 1-3-6. Player 2 confirms 1-3-6 is correct.

Let me now ask you a few questions:

- Can your app automatically decide who won the game, based on scores?
- Do you want to give Player 2 a chance to change scores after play has ended?
- What happens if Player 2 does not accept the score entered by Player 1?

I think the last point above is your primary question too, what if we allow Player 2 to change the score. Let's hypothesize what could happen in that case:

- May be Player 1 now won't accept Player 2's suggested scores, both unable to finalise a game score. It might not be a bad thing, as the score is disputed.
- May be Player 1 would accept Player 2's suggested score. The issue is resolved, and the game gets saved.